# FRESH INSTALL NEEDED? Error message: 'not all updates can be installed...'

Tags: boot, mount

error message, "may be due to unofficial software not provided by ubuntu".... or "problems with some of the installed software."  Have ISO on a USB, but can't change to boot sequence to USB when attempting to edit the BIOS.  PC is very buggy, and I have never installed anything not from the UBUNTU official repository.  I'm very much aware that some may think it's not the machine that's buggy, but me.  Have a vid of the machine doing a freak out here, see for yourself, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34N18qywczlU2V5V1FTZ1FYcUE/view

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try going through this guide and cleaning up some of the installed software?
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cleaning-up-a-ubuntu-gnulinux-system-updated-with-ubuntu-14-10-and-more-tools-added.html